# Add an additional field while serializing

Tags: rust, serde

In Serde serializers, how to add an additional field:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct X {
  a: u32,
  b: u32,
  c: u32,
}
```

I want to add to JSON serialization field `d` with value `"qwe"`. How without writing completely a serializer for `X` from scratch?

Answer (score 7):

A custom `Serialize` implementation isn't so bad:

```
use serde::ser::{Serialize, Serializer, SerializeStruct};

struct X {
  a: u32,
  b: u32,
  c: u32,
}

impl Serialize for X {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        let mut x = serializer.serialize_struct("X", 4)?;
        x.serialize_field("a", &self.a)?;
        x.serialize_field("b", &self.b)?;
        x.serialize_field("c", &self.c)?;
        x.serialize_field("d", "qwe")?;
        x.end()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you don't mind that the field `d` exists, but you just don't want it taking space in your struct, you can make it zero-sized and use the `serialize_with` attribute to emit the desired data when serializing:

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct X {
  a: u32,
  b: u32,
  c: u32,
  #[serde(serialize_with = "emit_qwe")]
  d: (),
}

fn emit_qwe<S: Serializer>(_: &(), s: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
    s.serialize_str("qwe")
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=82404895253d5d1677e2be939013dba2)

Comment: And if I need not `"qwe"`, but value of `c` in hexadecimal? (that's more similar to my real task)

Comment: In fact, I need to output `c` in serialization twice, in different representations.

Comment: @porton That's a different task than in the question, one for which the approach in this answer won't work.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a separate struct that's `#[derive(Serialize)]` and copy everything in your struct over

```rust
impl Serialize for X {
    fn serialize<S: serde::Serializer>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
        #[derive(Serialize)]
        struct XSerialize {
            a: u32,
            b: u32,
            c: u32,
            d: &'static str,
        }
        
        XSerialize {
            a: self.a,
            b: self.b,
            c: self.c,
            d: "only at serialization"
        }.serialize(serializer)
    }
}
```

This should allow you to compute a value for `d` as you specify in the comments.